# How to alter multiple objects in list c#

Tags: c#

The user must enter the name of the student and then enter the number of faults he has (the `numFaltas` column)

How do I change only the `numFalts` column and keep the rest?

Sorry for English. I'm learning yet.
Thank you!

My list:

```
alunosMatriculados.Add(new Aluno
{
    matAluno   = 1,
    nomeAluno  = "THIAGO BUARQUE",
    cpfAluno   = "111.111.111-11",
    turmaAluno = "3H",
    numFaltas  = 4
});

alunosMatriculados.Add(new Aluno
{
    matAluno   = 2,
    nomeAluno  = "MARIANA DA SILVA",
    cpfAluno   = "111.111.111-12",
    turmaAluno = "2I",
    numFaltas  = 0
});
```

Comment: When you post code, you should make sure the your readers can copy the code verbatim, paste it into a code editor and have it compile. Each line of your code is prefaced with a ">" which breaks this rule. I don't speak Spanish (but I do speak French). I'm pretty sure "faulta" would translate as "error" or "mistake" in English. I hope that's useful to you - I learn languages I've word at a time.

Comment: `foreach (Aluno item in alunosMatriculados) { item.numFaltas = 123; }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if (alunosMatriculados.Any(a => a.nomeAluno == inputName))
    alunosMatriculados.Where(a => a.nomeAluno == inputName).ToList().ForEach(a =>a.numFaltas = inputFaults);
```

But be careful because if there's more than one student with the same name you will change the faults for all of them. It would be better to make sure that the names are unique or use an unique field like an ID (maybe your `matAluno`)

Comment: No, OP can't do this, because I'm pretty sure `IEnumerable` does not have a property called `numFaltas`.

Comment: I assume the OP can use LINQ. And you were right, I forgot the ForEach.

Comment: I think there is another problem: this code is missing a `ToList()` after the `Where`.

Comment: Tried the code and you were right. Updated my answer. Ty.

Comment: Why would you need the if? It's just unnecessary additional work. The where will find all elements which have to be dealt with, anyways.

Comment: @derpirscher Added the if to help manage invalid input. The OP can add an else and warn the user.

Comment: @EverytimeIdid Ofc! I'm glad it worked.
So, first I check if there is any student with the name that the user picked - this is the if statement. You can add an else and warn the user about the invalid input. After that, I used the Where clause to get all students with the name that the user picked. With all the students with the given name, I used the ForEach to iterate them and set their "numFaltas" with the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in simple way by using foreach loop

You first verify that If your `inputName` parameter is null or not

Like

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputName))
{     
    foreach (Aluno a in alunosMatriculados)
        if (a.nomeAluno == inputName)
            a.numFaltas = inputValue;
}
```

in above code can comapre id also instead of inputName in inner if condition

By this way can only alter your numFaltas and any other also that you want

Comment: You're welcome. That's actually the first thanks I've gotten haha. Just out of curoisity, are you a VB programmer?

Comment: @AustinWBryan, actually i am a c# programmer but my intellisense suddenly not working :)

Comment: Thank you! it works. But... could you explain "if(!String.IsNullOrEmty(inpustName))" ??

Comment: Here we just verify whether "inputName" comes from caller method is not null or empty and then inner if condition will get exact "Aluno" object inside list and then we can override any property inside matched object . If "inputName" is null or empty then we cant get which item's property inside loop we have to override.

Comment: Finally we have to get exact "Aluno" item from list that match with "inputName" so this condition we checked . Does this make sense . If you hae doubts then let me know :)